# What is $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^2 - y^2} $?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^2 - y^2}
$$

Why is the result $8$ ?

Comment: $x^4-y^4=(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: These answers shouldn't mislead you into thinking that you will always have a unique answer for a limit over two variables.  It just happens to work out in this case, but in general, what path the variables take to approach the result can affect your solution.  Take for example $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y}{x}$, you could get zero, one, or infinity, or many other possible results.

Comment: Contrary to what many have mentioned here, the limit does not exist. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**
$$x^4-y^4 = (x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x,y\to{2,2}}\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^2-y^2}$$ $$= \lim_{x,y\to{2,2}}\frac{(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)}{x^2-y^2}$$

$$\lim_{x,y\to{2,2}} x^2+y^2 =...$$

Comment: Four minutes before you, a user provided a hint. It is respectful to wait for the OP to think about it instead of finishing it up, thus spoiling the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am really surprised (at other answers which have been upvoted) as to how we can think of the limit when the function $f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^{4} - y^{4}}{x^{2} - y^{2}}$ is not defined in a neighborhood of point $(2, 2)$. Note that the definition of $f(x, y)$ assumes that we must not have $x^{2} = y^{2}$ i.e. $x = \pm y$. So clearly in any neighborhood of point $(2, 2)$ we will will have points $(x, y)$ with $x = y$.

The limit of the function therefore does not exist.

**Update**: Please also check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364552/strange-behavior-of-lim-x-to0-frac-sin-leftx-sin-left-frac1x-right-right/) and [its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364635/) which deals with a similar scenario in single variable.

Comment: Why should the function be defined in a neighborhood of the point? All you need to define the limit is that the point is an accumulation point of the function's domain.

Comment: @egreg: Consider the case $f(x) = \sin(1/x)/\sin(1/x)$. This is defined for all $x$ except $x = 0$ and $x = 1/n\pi$. Clearly in this case the point $x = 0$ is an accumulation point of the domain. Do you really want to say that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 1$ in this case?

Comment: Why not? Where's the problem? The function *can* be extended to a function defined also on $0$ and continuous therein, which is exactly the purpose of limits.

Comment: @egreg: As far as I know the definition of $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ is that we should be able to get a $\delta > 0$ for any given $\epsilon > 0$ such that $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. This assumes that $f(x)$ is defined for all $x$ satisfying $ 0 < |x - a| < \delta$.

Comment: The question here is dealing with the usual definition of a limit in two variables and not with the specific kind of generalization which is more suitable in terms of metric spaces.

Comment: This of course depends on *what* definition you start with. I usually see the condition “for all $x$ in the domain such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ …”

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11953/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-egreg)

Answer (score 0):

The limit you are looking up to has a 'hole' in its value as $(x,y)\rightarrow(2,2)$. In order to eradicate that, we have to factor out the hole which is quite easy in this case. It can be done as follows:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(2,2)}\dfrac{x^4-y^4}{x^2-y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(2,2)}\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)}{x^2-y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(2,2)}x^2+y^2$$

Now we have successfully removed the 'hole' in the value by getting rid of the $\dfrac00$ format of the expression.

Now, substituting the values of $x$ and $y$ in the expression gives us,

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(2,2)}x^2+y^2=2^2+2^2=4+4=8$$